# (Swift or Python) How can I print a tree using only one table

Tags: python, swift, algorithm, recursion, tree

I have only one table(actually Dictionary), and want to print that result.
How can i do this. help me please !!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think a stack data structure will help you get the desired output.

When you start with a node, push all **direct** children from your dictionary to the stack.

Then start the processing. Every pop from the stack should be printed followed by a check if they have direct children. If so push them into the stack.

Reiterate the above step until the stack is empty.